# Get process argument info in windows with python/pywin32?

Tags: python, api, winapi, process, pywin32

In linux, I know with 'ps' you can get the arguments that a command was run with.  I need the equivalent in windows

Right now in python I'm doing

`Process[i] = subprocess.Popen(cmd + " --daemon --config " + str(i) + ".conf", shell=False)`

But I'm doing this in a daemon that is meant to be up all (or most) of the time.  Since I'm having to debug and modify this daemon regularly it's starting up 3 processes; but when I shut it down, the processes stay up.  (like should happen, just in case)...

When I start it back up again, I need to re-map the PID to the config file used by the processes that already exist, but I don't know of any way of retrieving this information (and parsing it) in windows.  Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440932/reading-command-line-arguments-of-another-process-win32-c-code) might give you some inspiration.

Comment: Thanks! - It led me to pywin32 + WMI python module; which has the ability to read processes and...even has a .commandline function!