# how to get the argument of ffmpeg process in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, ffmpeg

i am writing a simple program to get the all the properties of a process like ffmpeg . i got most  properties of predefined functions but i want to know the argument which i gave to the ffmpeg in vb.net?

```
  For Each prog As Process In Process.GetProcesses
        If prog.ProcessName = "ffmpeg" Then
            al.Add(prog.Id)
        End If
    Next

 For Each id In al  
   Dim p As Process = Process.GetProcessById(id)
   listBox3.Items.Add(Process.GetProcessById(id).ProcessName)
   ListBox3.Items.Add(p.BasePriority)
   ListBox3.Items.Add(p.HandleCount)
   ListBox3.Items.Add(p.Id)
   ListBox3.Items.Add(p.MainWindowTitle)
   ListBox3.Items.Add(p.MaxWorkingSet)
   ListBox3.Items.Add(p.MinWorkingSet)
   ListBox3.Items.Add(p.PriorityBoostEnabled)
   ListBox3.Items.Add(p.PriorityClass)
   ListBox3.Items.Add(p.PrivilegedProcessorTime)
   ListBox3.Items.Add(p.ProcessName)
   ListBox3.Items.Add(p.ProcessorAffinity)
   ListBox3.Items.Add(p.StartTime)
   ListBox3.Items.Add(p.TotalProcessorTime)
  ListBox3.Items.Add(p.UserProcessorTime)
  lastBox3.Items.Add(p.WaitForInputIdle)
  ListBox3.Items.Add("========================")
Next id
```

Comment: Try the [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2633674/2330053) using WMI by Jesse Slicer.

Comment: Can you give  a small example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Jesse Slicer's code as a base from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2633674/2330053):

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        For Each proc As Process In Process.GetProcessesByName("ffmpeg")
            Debug.Print("ID: " & proc.Id)
            Debug.Print("Arguments: " & proc.GetCommandLine)
            Debug.Print("------------------------------")
        Next
    End Sub

End Class

Public Module Extensions

    <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Function GetCommandLine(ByVal proc As Process) As String
        ' Project --> Add Reference --> System.Management
        Dim arguments As New System.Text.StringBuilder
        Using searcher As New Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT CommandLine FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId = " & proc.Id)
            For Each arg In searcher.Get
                arguments.Append(arg("CommandLine") & " ")
            Next
        End Using
        Return arguments.ToString.Trim
    End Function

End Module
```

Note that you need to add the System.Management reference, and I made the function an extension method of the Process class.

Answer (score -2):

ffmpeg is open source, so Might it will be useful:
https://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html