# Get command line from calling process

Tags: c#, command-line, process, command-line-arguments

We use a software which is capable of using scripts for different tasks.

In one script I want to start a little helper tool to input some additional data. Therefore I need to know the command line parameters of the calling software shown in the picture below.

[image: TaskManager - Command line parameters]

Is there a possibility to get these from the calling process or at least to get them by looking for the "Image Name"?

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633628/can-i-get-command-line-arguments-of-other-processes-from-net-c help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining the link from Wapac's comment with the Simon Mourier's answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394816/how-to-get-parent-process-in-net-in-managed-way) question solved the problem.

Now I have two helper classes:

1. [CommandLineUtilities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34071167/3501759)
2. [ParentProcessUtilities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3346055/3501759)

In my program I just need to call now:

```
Process process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
Process parent = ParentProcessUtilities.GetParentProcess(process.Id);
String[] parameters = CommandLineUtilities.getCommandLinesParsed(parent);
```