# Is there a way to distinguish which batch file ran an executable?

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file, cmd

For instance, let's say I have a folder with the following in it:

- `log.bat`
- `clear.bat`
- `new.bat`
- `init.exe`

Each `.bat` file calls `init` once or more times. I do **not** have access to any of the `.bat` files, so there is not way that I can pass a variable to `init.exe`. One thing to know about `init` is a C# application and can accept arguments.

Possibilities:

- **DOSKEYS** - Turns out that they don't work for `.bat` files.
- **Environment Variables** - I thought I could name an environment variable called `init` that would do something like `init %~n0` to get the batch file name. Sadly, this doesn't work either.
- **Hacky Alias** - Make a batch file named `init.bat` (as the `.bat` files call `init`, **not** `init.exe`). Then, in the `init.bat` file, I would simply put `init.exe %~n0`. Two things went wrong with this. First, the `.bat` files for some reason took `init.exe` priority over `init.bat`, and so the batch file alias wasn't even called. Secondly, the `%~n0` part expanded to `init`, as it was called from `init.bat`, not the other batch files.

Am I out of luck? Or is there a hacky method that could work for this?

Comment: How is this a C# question?

Comment: @rory.ap Sorry for that. The `init.exe` file is a c# application, so I thought maybe it was worthy of tagging.

Comment: Where are you trying to make this determination?  From code running somewhere else?  or manually from Windows?

Comment: @rory.ap Anywhere. I don't think I have many options at this point.

Comment: Is init.exe a console app or windows app?

Comment: @alstonp, console app

Comment: Have you checked the `static void Main(string[] args)` array? It should contain some information about the caller?

Comment: @alstonp, Does it? `Debug.WriteLine(args.Length)` returns `0`.

Comment: Guess not, sorry, my mistake. So we can't modify the way the bat files call init.exe right?

Comment: That is correct. Also, the `.bat` files call `init`, not `init.exe`, if that helps.

Comment: The order of extension is set in the `pathext` variable. Type `set pathext` to see.

Comment: Can you recompile your program to make changes to that?

Comment: It's possible to convert .bat to .exe so take your own init.bat and convert it and replace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ideas of both Remi and Noodles helped me come to this answer. In C#, I used the following to get the PID of the terminal calling the executable:

```
//Get PID of current terminal
//Reference: https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/getCmdPID.bat

var myId = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
var query = String.Format("SELECT ParentProcessId FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId = {0}", myId);
var search = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", query);
var results = search.Get().GetEnumerator();
if (!results.MoveNext())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error");
    Environment.Exit(-1);
}

var queryObj = results.Current;
var parentId = queryObj["ParentProcessId"];
int myPid = Convert.ToInt32(parentId);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
C:\Windows\system32>wmic process where "commandline like 'notepad'" get parentprocessid
ParentProcessId
5908


C:\Windows\system32>wmic process where "processid=5908" get commandline
CommandLine
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c ""C:\Users\User\Desktop\New Text Document (2.bat" "
```

Or to see all info on that batch process

```
wmic process where "processid=5908" get /format:list
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most elegant solution, but if there's only one of those batch file running at a given time, you could try to list all the `cmd.exe` processes with `Process.GetProcessesByName("cmd"),` then find the one running one of the batch file by extracting its command line argument using this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2633674/6621790