# Getting "Image File" info as displayed by Process Explorer, in C#

Tags: c#, pid, process-explorer, windows-process

I am Working with a Windows project that manages a python program as a System.Diagnostics.Process object through an C# WPF GUI. Somehow, the PyQt5-based sub-process does not quit after the process object is killed and my main program exits, now as a separate Python process in Process Explorer.

I assume its way of escaping is by taking a different process Id than that of the command line process. May be it gained that as I launched a conda command line in that parent command line process to launch the python code.

Anyway, with Explorer I can luckily identify the zombie process by its (right-click)Properties->Image->Command line, which kept the command line arguments I launched it with. How may I get that info in C# so I can kill it upon closing?

Comment: See [Can I get command line arguments of other processes from .NET/C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2633674/10318835)

Comment: @Steeeve Exactly! Thank you!