# How to get process.startInfo.Arguments of a process from its pid in c# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, process

I have a process which have something like...

```
Process.startInfo.Arguments = "abc";
```

I am calling a different function where I am fetching process instance from processId( which is stored in db)

I am getting every info related to process but not the one stored in StartInfo of a process
Like process.StartInfo.Arguments is returning ""(empty string) instead of returning "abc".

.Net mvc framework,c# solution please...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I get command line arguments of other processes from .NET/C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633628/can-i-get-command-line-arguments-of-other-processes-from-net-c)

Comment: This is not working for me

Comment: Which of the solutions from @Renat's link did you try?  The C# solution looked promising to me.

Comment: I am not using console application and managementObjectSearcher is throwing access denied exception