How to reliably map window titles to executable names in C#?
I am trying to map the window titles of running applications to their corresponding executable names in C#. Currently, I am using the GetWindowText() method to retrieve the window title and manually mapping the title to the executable name.
Here's my current implementation:
public string GetWindowTitle(IntPtr window)
{
    StringBuilder title = new StringBuilder(10000);
    if (GetWindowText(window, title, 10000) > 0)
    {
        return title.ToString();
    }
    return "";
}

public string GetGeneralName(string windowTitle)
{
    if (windowTitle.Contains("Microsoft Visual Studio"))
    {
        return "devenv";
    }
    if (windowTitle.Contains("Brave"))
    {
        return "brave";
    }
    if (windowTitle.Contains("Google Chrome"))
    {
        return "chrome";
    }
    if (windowTitle.Contains("Visual Studio Code"))
    {
        return "Code";
    }
    return "";
}

The problem with this approach is that it doesn't work for window titles that are not listed in the GetGeneralName method.
For example, if the window title is "Process - Microsoft Visual Studio", I want to map it to "devenv" dynamically without hardcoding the mapping.

This answer will get you the path to the process for a given PID: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633628/can-i-get-command-line-arguments-of-other-processes-from-net-c. Then you can go window title -> pid of that window -> image filename of that pid

Also something like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/getprocesshandlefromhwnd could help to get underlying process from selected window.

@Evelyn ya that worked for me getting name from the processId

Use the Process.GetProcesses() to get all processes and then check for the respective names of the processes you need. Then check for the MainWindowTitle and get the title of it. Check the title of it via a stored array or dictionary and check.
Refer the code below:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

public class WindowUtils
{
    
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out int processId);


    private Dictionary<string, string> titleToExecutableMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public WindowUtils() // Add more mappings as required via a dictionary or a array
    {

        titleToExecutableMap["Microsoft Visual Studio"] = "devenv";
        titleToExecutableMap["Brave"] = "brave";
        titleToExecutableMap["Google Chrome"] = "chrome";
        titleToExecutableMap["Visual Studio Code"] = "Code";
        
    }

    public string GetExecutableNameFromWindowTitle(string windowTitle) // get executable names
    {
        foreach (var mapping in titleToExecutableMap)
        {
            if (windowTitle.Contains(mapping.Key))
            {
                return mapping.Value;
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    public string GetActiveWindowTitle() //get current active window title
    {
        IntPtr hWnd = GetForegroundWindow();
        StringBuilder title = new StringBuilder(1000);
        if (GetWindowText(hWnd, title, title.Capacity) > 0)
        {
            return title.ToString();
        }
        return "";
    }

    public string GetActiveWindowExecutableName()
    {
        string activeWindowTitle = GetActiveWindowTitle();
        return GetExecutableNameFromWindowTitle(activeWindowTitle);
    }

    public Dictionary<string, string> GetAllRunningProcesses()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> runningProcesses = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
        foreach (Process process in processes)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(process.MainWindowTitle))
                {
                    string executableName = GetExecutableNameFromWindowTitle(process.MainWindowTitle);
                    runningProcesses.Add(process.MainWindowTitle, executableName);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return runningProcesses;
    }
}


sorry for the late reply, but in this we will still need to map the window title to the exe names. What i wanted was a way to get exe name without mapping
